# Google Sheets ArrayFormula with Index or Offset

Tags: google-sheets, lookup-tables, array-formulas

I am making a spreadsheet template to convert database information and am looking for a more automated way of doing this. Currently I have a Catalog of items and a List of Assets. My goal is to read all the assets' Product Name and look it up in the Catalog and pull the row of information on that product.

I am able to create an arraylist to match a list of Product Names in the Catalog, (this returns a list of indices corresponding to the Catalog)

`=ArrayFormula(match(Data!T3:T,Data!L3:L,0))`

and I am able to pull the information of a single Product Name from the Catalog. (This returns the row at the index where the Product Name was found in the Catalog)

`=index(Catalog,match(Data!T3,Data!L3:L,0))`

However, when I attempt to combine the operations into

`=ArrayFormula(index(Catalog,match(Data!T3:T,Data!L3:L,0)))`

the ArrayFormula doesn't work and it just pulls the information of the first item in the list.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong or if ArrayFormula even has the capability to do something like this?

Here is a link to an example Spreadsheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ML-jAx2O_0FY0p42ytVmJEF12P92mi4WOa1wl2Wx8tY/edit#gid=1397027595

Thank you

Comment: Can you please add a link to a sample spreadsheet?

Comment: I have put a link to an sample of what i'm working on. I also ran into the problem that using the OR statement with arraylists doesn't work either. (as written in the student_staff_ID column)

Comment: The permissions aren't correct on the doc yet, you need to make them available to anyone for me to see it

Comment: permissions have been set to be public

Comment: thanks i'll take a look after work later today :)

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not 100% sure if this is what your specifically asking, but arrayformula doesn't work to pull more in this particular case, but for example if you place this formula in B6 and copy the same formula down, it matches that section etc and you can continue to modify it based on which pieces of data you want back.

```
=INDEX(Data!M:Q,MATCH(A6,Data!L:L,0))
```

The spreadsheet does seem to be working incredibly slow though, even without that much data on the sample - are you importing something else in there?

Comment: That is kind of what I originally had, but i was looking at getting away from having to manually copy down several rows for each new asset check added. And it does seem to be running incredibly slow for such little calculation. I believe the arrayformula I have in H6 and K6 are checking all blank values in the column as well. I maybe just be asking too much from a spreadsheet.

Comment: Yeah, sorry its not much of a better solution - what I tend to do on all the sheets Ive created for various reasons, is wrap all my function with "if(istext(A1), bunch of other code, etc)" So what ever value it's dependant on, it only slows down the sheet and runs if there is relevant data in there for it to process